# finding points on the line connecting two 3D points

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I have two points in 3D space. Say these are `P = (x, y, z)` and `Q = (u, v, w)`. Now, I would like to get line segments from P to Q of length `epsilon` each. So, for that, I need all the points on the line from P to Q that are apart by length epsilon. I can do this for a line in 2D, but I am confused with how to do this for a line in 3D?

Here is what I tried.

Set  current point to be `P` and the next point to be `current point + epsilon * (Q-P)/|Q-P|`.

Z = {current point, next point}

Then, iteratively, went through adding to the set `Z`, `next point +  epsilon * (Q-P)/|Q-P|`.

However, I can not figure out how to stop this iterative process.

What is the correct way of thinking about this in 3D?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Find unit vector $ \hat{u}$ in the direction $PQ$, then the other end of the line segment is $ ~ P + \epsilon ( \hat{u})$

Comment: Should the unit vector in the direction of PQ simply be (Q - P)/norm(Q - P)? How do I ensure that the segments do not go out of the line connecting the points PQ?

Comment: unit vector? Yes $(Q-P) / |Q-P|$

Comment: I tried this, but I can not figure out how to check that it does not go beyond  Q. If you write it as an answer, I can "checkmark" it.

Comment: But that depends on $\epsilon$. If you want the point to be between $P$ and $Q$ then you must ensure $ \epsilon \leq |Q-P|$

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Simply go on |P-Q|/epsilon many times. So, if you put a formal solution, I can "checkmark" it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of line segments ($n$) of length $\epsilon$ starting from point $P$ and ending at or before point $Q$ must be,

$ \displaystyle n = \left \lfloor \frac{|\textbf{Q}-\textbf{P}|}{\epsilon} \right \rfloor$

At the start of the iteration, $ \textbf{P}_{1} = \textbf{P}$

Iterate for $1 \leq m \leq n$,

$ \displaystyle \small  \textbf{Q}_m = \textbf {P}_m + \frac{\textbf{Q}-\textbf{P}}{|\textbf{Q}-\textbf{P}|} \epsilon ~$

and $\textbf{P}_{m+1} = \textbf{Q}_{m}$